# Complexity of the homomorphism problem parameterized by treewidth

Tags: graph-algorithms, parameterized-complexity, treewidth, fixed-parameter-tractable, homomorphism

The *homomorphism problem* $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{G}, \mathcal{H})$ for two
classes $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ of graphs is defined as follows:

> **Input:** a graph $G$ in $\mathcal{G}$, a graph $H$ in $\mathcal{H}$
>
> **Output:** decide if there is a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$, i.e.,
>     a mapping $h$ from the vertices of $G$ to those of $H$ such that,
>     for any edge $\{x, y\}$ of $G$, $\{h(x), h(y)\}$ is an edge of $H$.

For each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, I will call $\mathcal{T}_k$ the class of the
graphs of [treewidth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth) at most
$k$. I'm interested in the problem $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{T}_k, \mathcal{T}_k)$,
which I see as a *parameterized* problem (by the treewidth bound $k$). My
question is: **what is the complexity of this parameterized problem?**
Is it known to be FPT? or is it W[1]-hard?

Here are some things that I found about the $\text{Hom}$ problem, but which do
not help me answer the question. (I write $-$ for the class of all graphs.)

- http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009589569090132J:
  If $\mathcal{H}$ is bipartite then $\text{Hom}(-, \mathcal{H})$ is in PTIME,
  otherwise it is NP-complete, but of course the NP-hardness relies on
  allowing arbitrary $G$.
- http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.9013&rep=rep1&type=pdf: If the treewidth of $\mathcal{G}$ (modulo homomorphic equivalence)
  is bounded by a constant then $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{G}, -)$ is in PTIME (and
  otherwise it isn't, assuming FPT != W[1]). Hence, in particular my
  problem $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{T}_k, \mathcal{T}_k)$ is in PTIME for fixed $k$,
  but this doesn't tell me what is the dependency on the parameter.
- From Flum and Grohe's book *Parameterized Complexity Theory*, Corollary
  13.17: The problem $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{T}_k, -)$ is FPT when parameterized
  by the *size* of $G$ (but I am parameterizing by the treewidth)
- http://users.uoa.gr/~sedthilk/papers/homo.pdf, Corollary 3.2: When
  fixing a specific graph $H$, the problem $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{T}_k, \{H\})$,
  parameterized by k, is FPT (this even holds for more complicated
  counting variants), but I do not want to restrict to fixed $H$.

Comment: This question is still open, but one remark: there is an FPT algorithm parameterized by treewidth for the graph *isomorphism* problem, here: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/140999980?casa_token=OrIKxCNZqLMAAAAA:qEirJxxxmjhOKqX_Vo-glRJRlQzd1zooZjfC0I4ZtfF98Qru4CcwXzc89ufpayw1_8NTIKDOqsz8     (Daniel Lokshtanov, Marcin Pilipczuk, Michał Pilipczuk, and Saket Saurabh, "Fixed-Parameter Tractable Canonization and Isomorphism Test for Graphs of Bounded Treewidth", SICOMP.) As far as I know, unfortunately, this does not say anything about the homomorphism problem.